# .NET MAUI Adjust entry max length to screen width

Tags: maui

I am creating an application in which I need a specific function so that the user can enter text in the entry element only in the visible area of the screen. That is, so that the entry property "MaxLength" is associated with the "WidthRequest" property of the parent element. Is there any way to do this on Android and other platforms?

Comment: this will be difficult because the max number of characters will vary with the font type and size, and you would have to use a monospace font to accurately calculate the number of characters that will fit

Comment: @Jason Well, I basically thought I'd have to do what you said. In principle, the font will be standard and will not change, as well as the size of the font, but it all looks like a bad solution. I'm just trying to do something like a skip job. Like there is some text that the user writes and there you can insert a skip in which the person will choose an option. Something like that. Maybe you can suggest something? I was also considering an option with absolute layout, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it

Comment: I'd try just trial and error to determine the max number of "average" sized characters that will fit in the entry at various screen widths, and then build a formula to calculate that

Comment: @Jason Let's say there are no problems with this. I'm trying to make sure that the user can insert a space anywhere in the text. The space is any ui element, for example, just a button, which will always be a fixed size. The question is how to understand how many characters this button takes and how to determine, for example, if the user reaches the end of the line, then how to understand whether I can still insert this element on this line or I should move on to another. In short, I have much more questions than what I can actually do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the device height and width.

```
void getDeviceInfo()
    {

        // Get Metrics
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        //HEIGHT
        var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
        // Screen density
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        Console.WriteLine("DEVICE WIDTH : " + width + " DEVICE HEIGHT :"+ height + " DEVICE DENSITY : "+ density);

        var mywidthrequest = (width / density) * 0.9;
        Width = mywidthrequest;

    }
```

Then, you can bind the `Width` to the entry element.

Answer (score 0):

SkiaSharp is cross-platform, and has good methods for placing and measuring text. Make a custom component, and write code so it behaves like an Entry.

Since you also want to place UI elements, I'd make three layers:

- AbsoluteLayout to hold UI elements.
- SKCanvasView, to hold Skia text at desired locations.
- An Entry to receive what user types, so you can use its TextChanged event to intercept the characters. Hide this by giving SKCanvasView a background color.

Below are three layers, on top of each other. InputTransparent is used in the top two, so that input characters go to the Entry. The entry is hidden by the layer above; its just there to receive the characters.

```xml
<Grid ...
    x:Class="MyMagicEntry">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="buttonsLayer" InputTransparent="True" />
    <SKCanvasView x:Name="skiaLayer" PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" 
 InputTransparent="True" />
    <Entry x:Name="entry" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />
```

Add buttons to buttonsLayer, in c# code behind. Maintain a list of buttons, so you can access them to set position, and read width/height.

Its easiest if each button has HeightRequest and WidthRequest, so that width/height is known even before they are drawn.

Text you'll maintain as a list of strings, with (x,y) positions.

Method `Entry_TextChanged` will be called as characters are typed.
After altering text list, call `skiaLayer.InvalidateSurface();` to redraw the texts, via `OnPaintSurface`.

Method `OnPaintSurface` needs code to render your text strings.

Skia works in pixels, not DIPs, so multiply button width/height (DIPs) by device `Density`, to get pixels.

There's a lot to learn here, but once you learn it, you'll have more control over text layout than Maui gives you.